# Best way to Design Relational Silverlight Diagram

Tags: silverlight, diagramming

I want to design an associate silverlight diagraming surface where you can type in boxes, and then drag these boxes around and link them up to other boxes using lines, arrows.  My first problem is what is the first step to take to go about this approach?  I am looking for something like a mindmap or visio diagram.

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer to this question for anyone who is interested: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/23895/89599.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Hi give a try to SilverDiagram (it contains a free and commercial license):

Demo

http://www.silverdiagram.net/Scripts/SD.Client.MainTestPage.aspx

Site

http://www.silverdiagram.net/Projects/Silverdiagram.aspx

Samples

http://silverdiagram.codeplex.com/